# Using R to forecast future values

Tags: r

I am currently doing an exercise and i am suppose to do a prediction for the next year using multiple linear regression but i am having error.

[image]

The linear regression is working but i can't predict the future values using R.

```
mod5 <- tslm(tsdata[,5]~tsdata[,10]+tsdata[,11]+tsdata[,12]+tsdata[,13]+tsdata[,14]+tsdata[,28]+tsdata[,29]+tsdata[,30]+tsdata[,31]+tsdata[,32]+tsdata[, 15] + tsdata[, 16] + tsdata[,17]+tsdata[,18]+tsdata[,6]+tsdata[,7]+tsdata[,8]+tsdata[,9]+tsdata[,1])
fmod5 <- forecast(mod5,h=12)
```

```
tsdata <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 76, 115, 77, 84, 114, 87, 59, 64, 59, 48, 80, 
78, 0.56, 0.4, 0.61, 0.58, 0.66, 0.7, 0.13, 0.12, 0.18, 0.22, 
0.23, 0.19, 0.19, 0.43, 0.2, 0.19, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.03, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.26, 0.24, 0.14, 0.3, 0.28, 0.22, 0.27, 0.43, 0.2, 0.19, 
0.09, 0.14, 0.26, 0.13, 0.11, 0.11, 0.26, 0.26, 0.19, 0.13, 0.42, 
0.32, 0.31, 0.26, 0, 0.06, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.09, 0.4, 0.53, 
0.29, 0.27, 0.28, 0.1, 0.39, 0.21, 0.53, 0.45, 0.54, 0.65, 0.19, 
0.25, 0.16, 0.27, 0.17, 0.24, 0.25, 0.51, 0.51, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.26, 0.21, 0.05, 0.08, 0.14, 0.32, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0, 0.01, 0.06, 0.08, 0.17, 0.12, 0.27, 
0.23, 0.15, 0.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.33, 0.42, 0.34, 0.36, 
0.19, 0.06, 0.01, 0.02, 0.07, 0.2, 0.06, 0.1, 0.06, 0.22, 0.25, 
0.06, 0, 0.27, 0.31, 0.42, 0.5, 0.51, 0.44, 0.21, 0.15, 0.29, 
0.15, 0.21, 0.14, 0.4, 0.46, 0.05, 0.09, 0.21, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.06, 0.22, 0.25, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0087, 0.01, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.06, 0.01, 0.06, 0.11, 0.04, 0, 0.76, 
0.9, 0.68, 0.59, 0.77, 0.94, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0087, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0.01, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.1, 0.05, 0, 0, 
0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.03, 
0.00877, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.00877, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0.0087, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0087, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.01, 0, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 98, 92, 
101, 110, 100), .Dim = c(6L, 67L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("period", 
"year", "month", "numadmit", "numrt", "cc1", "cc2", "cc3", "cc4", 
"hr1", "hr2", "hr3", "hr4", "hr5", "age1", "age2", "age3", "female", 
"tumEA", "tumLA", "tumLP", "tumNC", "tumOC", "tumOT", "tumPH", 
"tumSL", "tumTH", "c0", "c1", "c3", "c4", "c7", "h800", "h801", 
"h802", "h803", "h804", "h805", "h807", "h808", "h809", "h812", 
"h814", "h820", "h824", "h826", "h829", "h831", "h833", "h834", 
"h835", "h843", "h844", "h848", "h850", "h851", "h852", "h855", 
"h856", "h868", "h894", "h908", "h949", "h950", "h952", "h972", 
"numdiag")), .Tsp = c(1, 1.41666666666667, 12), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

Comment: Post some data, which packages you're using, and the error message.

Comment: i am using fpp2, forecast,

Comment: Thsi are my fitted value but i want to have the prediction for the next year:

Comment: You can use `dput(head(tsdata))` to show some of your data (edit the original question and paste the results in there).

Comment: Thank you Mister @EricKrantz i  did modifications

Comment: No it is not working but is it possible to used the predict fonction

Comment: @henryTadja Did you check  the answer given below?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have values for predictor/feature variables, unless they are month or season, for the prediction to work.

It is also best to try and use the formula format in the tslm function to make things easier. Here's an example from the [book fpp2](https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-regression.html).

```
fit.consBest <- tslm(Consumption ~ Income + Savings + Unemployment,
                   data = uschange)

newdata <- data.frame(
              Income = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
              Savings = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
              Unemployment = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

fcast.up <- forecast(fit.consBest, newdata = newdata)
```